# How to use callActivity programmatically and send context to the first step in Activity?

Tags: activiti

I would like to call other activity from inside a step, and send `DelegateExecution (context)` to this sub process.

Comment: Why do you want that? I think that better way is use gateway and call sub process from process. The business logic, if sub-process will be called, is on gateway transition.

Comment: I want to that becuase I have to pass variables to the sub-process. How can I do it programmatically ?

Comment: First, put variables to the process by ServiceTask (define variables programmatically in Java handler), before calling sub-process. These variables let pass to sub-process by process definition. More information http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnCallActivityPassVariables